# Impossible to install Gatsby 409 Conflict: convert-hrtime@^2.0.0

Tags: gatsby, http-status-code-409

I am trying to install Gatsby on mac and this is what happens
npm ERR! code E409
npm ERR! 409 Conflict: convert-hrtime@^2.0.0

Then I found how to install gatsby 2 like that npm install --global gatsby-cli@next
and this is the result 
npm ERR! code E409
npm ERR! 409 Conflict: currently-unhandled@^0.4.1

I really don't know how to solve that
before that I have upgraded node to 11.6.0 using nvm

Comment: I realize that I can install it on my Imac which stays with sierra, I just updated my macbook to mojave, can it be the reason, and what can I do ?

Comment: is this the first time you install gatsby, or is this an upgrade?